# Using iframe tag to display PDFs in firefox results in popup window

Tags: html, css, pdf, firefox, iframe

I was using the iframe tag to display some PDFs on a website and they were working fine.

```
<iframe src="M3-Presentation-Slides.pdf" width="100%" height="500px">
      </iframe>
```

However, now firefox displays the "what should Firefox do with this file?" window whenever the page loads. Everything still works normally on chrome. Is this related to some recent firefox update or is there some way to fix it within my hmtl code? Any help to resolving this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this recently, and the issue does seem to be an issue with Firefox itself. [This bug report in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1662216) seems to suggest that iframes are affected by Firefox's action when downloading PDFs for some reason, not sure why.

To change those actions, go into your preferences (Settings > General (tab) > Files and Applications > Applications, or just search "Applications" on the settings page) and change the "Action" for the Portable Document Format (PDF) content type to "Open in Firefox". That fixed things for me.

[image: A table in the Firefox settings page, under the Application subheading. The table columns are "Content Type" and "Action". The row with "Portable Document Format (PDF)" has the "Open in Firefox" action.]

Answer (score -1):

try adding `type="application/pdf"`

like this :

```
<iframe src="M3-Presentation-Slides.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
```

Comment: No that didn't change anything